# How to export typings along with a module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm writing a module that adds some functionalities to testing suites our team is using. It's a project that has main typescript file, that wraps other exports from our project.

index.d.ts:

```
export * from "./OneModule"
export * from "./AnotherModule"
```

One of the modules has a functionality of adding new methods to `Chai.js` assertion library. This is achieved by using it's functions for adding new methods, for example:

```
assertion.addChainableMethod('newMethod', callback, chainCallback)
```

will add ability to write statements like `expect(something).to.be.newMethod()`. TypeScript though, doesn't recognize those new methods, since the type Assertion in `@types/chai` obviously doesn't have those functions.

I've created interface definition to be merged with the Chai Assertion like this:

```
declare namespace Chai {
    interface Assertion {
        newMethod(something: string): Assertion;
        newMethod: Assertion;
    }
}
```

The addChainableMethod adds new method so it can be also chaines as `expect(something).to.be.newMethod.equals()` that's why it has to be defined both as property and method.

The problem is, no matter how I add the above declaration to index.d.ts the new assertions aren't visible in the importing project. I suspect it's somehow wrapped in module namespace(but I might be very wrong about that). I know I can do `@types/newAssertions` and define them there, but that requires users to include 2 projects in `package.json`, and also requires our developers to handle 2 projects at once. How can I export both my Chai namespace extension and all the modules I have?

The best I've managed to do is something like that:

```
declare module 'my-module' {
    function AddNewAssertions(chai: any, utils: any): void;
}
declare namespace Chai {
    interface Assertion { //same as above }
}
```

But with this I cannot expose my other modules, and it works only when I'm only exposing AddNewAssertions function, which adds those assertions. This works perfectly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knocked up a very basic test app for this, and I had some success with adding:

```
declare global {
    namespace Chai {
        interface Assertion {
            newMethod(something: string): Assertion;
            newMethod: Assertion;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes the extension visible in your other modules, not just the one with the declaration.