# Using custom typeRoots and still exporting those types along with entrypoint

Tags: typescript, npm, rollupjs

In my project, I use rollup to bundle a corresponding `index.d.ts` (and `index.js`) for my entrypoint `src/index.ts`.

Internally, I have a folder of `src/types` with several `.d.ts` files. These types are available in global scope within my project because `src/types` is in my `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`.

However, since the *entrypoint* to my project is `index.ts`, these *global* types are not exported to users of my npm module. I would have to redeclare and re-export all of them in my `index.ts` file for them to be importable outside my project. Is there a way to include (`///reference`) my type definitions in `src/types` through my entrypoint `index.ts` while preserving the handy global access within my project?

Example:

```
// src/types/foo.d.ts

interface Foo {
  bar: string;
}

// many many more types....
```

```
// src/index.ts

// suppose it is very inconvenient for me to
// instead use myProject.Foo or some other prefix:

export const HelloWorld = (input: Foo) => console.log("hello world", input.bar);
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
...
"compilerOptions": {
   ...,
   "declaration": true,
   "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types"]
}
...
}
```

And in a hypothetical consumption of my project:

```
import {HelloWorld, Foo} from "myModuleAbove";

const input: Foo = {bar: "hi"};
HelloWorld(input);
```

Is the approach similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47939706/10833799?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm just going to  stop using `typeRoots` and `.d.ts`, per the advice of [Best practice for exporting types from declaration file to external project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64068405/best-practice-for-exporting-types-from-declaration-file-to-external-project/64078798#64078798).